# Trying to allow Remote Desktop connections via wmic command line but everytime Windows return me an error

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, remote-desktop, wmi

I'm working on a project that I need to [allow Windows Remote Desktop connections](http://www.vedivi.com/support/blog/71-how-to-enable-remote-desktop-programmatically.html) with the wmic interface using the following command:

> wmic RDToggle where servername=”ServerName" call SetAllowTSConnections
>   1

But everytime I try to execute the `wmic RDToggle command` it returns me the same error(I already tested it on three different machines with the same result):

[image]

As you can see, not even WMIC command to query TS Connections settings is working...

Am I forgetting something before running the command??? Any tips?

PS: I'm running cmd from elevated mode....

Comment: For the first one, try wrapping %COMPUTERNAME% in quotes to get rid of the "unexpected switch" error (I'm pretty sure it's caused by the hyphen in the PC's name): `servername="%COMPUTERNAME%"`

Comment: For the second one, if you copy/pasted it, try typing it out manually to ensure there's no weird web-encoded characters. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just typed in wmic RDToggle get AllowTSConnections. My cmd window ran the command fine; in my case it stated this

C:\Windows\System32> wmic RDToggle get AllowTSConnections
AllowTSConnections
0

C:\Windows\System32> (Blinking cursor)

I dont know what to tell you.

Type ipconfig/all and post that, then type netstat and post that too. I'll take a look into it for you. Also, I haven't messed with command line in ages so I am venturing in to old seas again. I'll have to read up and familiarize myself. I'll be back in an hour!

-Xenith

~~~~EDIT~~~~

I came back and found something relevant to your problem. I was trying to replicate your problem on my PC and couldn't exactly do it. Give this a shot:

The behavior seems to be caused by a failure to mofcomp specific mof/mfl
files on that machine. The logs in %windir%\system32\wbem\logs might give
you a clue why the root\cimv2 namespace is missing. If that doesn't help,
try to rebuild the WMI repository by running the following batch.

Net stop winmgmt /y
If exist "%windir%\system32\wbem\repository.old" rmdir /s/q
"%windir%\system32\wbem\repository.old"

Rename "%windir%\system32\wbem\repository"
"%windir%\system32\wbem\repository.old"

for /f %s in ('dir /b /s %windir%\system32\wbem*.dll') do regsvr32 /s %s

--
Andy Cheung
Microsoft WMI Test Engineer

All credit goes to Andy Cheung.

PS: What OS are you running?

[Here's some useful bits and pieces for WMIC that you might be interested in...](http://www.computerhope.com/wmic.htm)

Answer (score 0):

To find out the Remote Desktop status

```
wmic /node:"REMOTE_COMPUTER" rdtoggle list brief
```

where "0" means Disabled, and "1" means Enabled.
To change the status to "Enabled"

```
wmic /node:"REMOTE_COMPUTER" rdtoggle where allowtsconnections="0" call setallowtsconnections "1"
```

Don't forget to run the command line as domain administrator.